# jQuery: append() isn't inserting any elements into selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

First and foremost, this is my code.

```
var size = 400

function createGrid(size) {
  $("#create").click(function() {
    for (i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
      $("#container").append('<div class="grid"> </div>');
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(createGrid);
```

```css
#container {
  top: 10px;
  position: relative;
  width: 960px;
  height: 960px;
  border-color: black;
  margin: auto;
  outline: 2px solid black;
}
.grid {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background-color: black;
  float: left;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>
  Sam's Etcha Sketch
</title>

<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <button id="create">Create!</button>
  </div>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

My goal is to create square divs inside `#container` after clicking on the button `#create`. I don't mind how ugly it looks right now, I just want to be able to click on the button to add squares(which isn't the result as of now). I checked JS Bin and my browser console for any bugs or errors but I can't seem to find any. Not sure what I'm doing wrong as I tried a simple FadeOut function on the button and it didn't seem to work, so maybe it's the way I placed the  into the HTML? (I tried placing it inside  as well.)

TL;DR

What is wrong with my code that is causing my `click()` function to not append any square divs inside a container?

Comment: Remove the  param `size` passed to the function `createGrid(size)`. You are not passing anything to the function on `document.ready` and its expecting `size`.

Comment: size is already available to the function. So, do not pass it when defining/calling your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're never passing `size` to `createGrid`

Here's your code.

```
// the outer "size" variable
var size = 400

// this creates a new "size" variable which shadows the outer one
function createGrid(size) {
  $("#create").click(function() {
    for (i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
      $("#container").append('<div class="grid"> </div>');
    }
  });
}

// this passes "createGrid" to the event handler, which calls it without any argument
$(document).ready(createGrid);
```

Here's how to do it:

```
// this generates an event handler with a custom "size" in its scope
function getGridCreator(container, size) {
  return function () {
    $("#create").click(function() {
      for (i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
        $(container).append('<div class="grid"> </div>');
      }
    });
  };
}

// this passes the grid creator to the event handler, which again calls 
// it without any argument, but this time "size" is in scope
$(document).ready(getGridCreator("#container", 400));
```

As a general tip: Avoid global variables, use function parameters and closures instead.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I was going for the custom "size" but I wanted to get the button to work first, which I realized I didn't call the function properly earlier... Thanks for clarifying the importance of when to use globals!

Answer (score 1):

Try this i made a few changes in your script

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var size = 400

function createGrid(size) {
  $("#create").click(function() {
    for (i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
      $("#container").append($('<div class="grid"/>'));
    }
  });
}
    createGrid(size)

  });
```

```css
#container {
  top: 10px;
  position: relative;
  width: 960px;
  height: 960px;
  border-color: black;
  margin: auto;
  outline: 2px solid black;
}
.grid {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background-color: black;
  float: left;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>
  Sam's Etcha Sketch
</title>

<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <button id="create">Create!</button>
  </div>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! Before I read this, I made a change to call the function after everything in my old code. I still kept the document.ready at the bottom and it did what I wanted. Is the point of adding the document.ready at the beginning to "ready" the function when the page loads?

Comment: @SKSam Works anyway i just like the `document.ready` at the top